# Find specific term in a text string and return that term in the previous column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For a reason I can't figure out the first return is working but when I drag down the other result are returned as #VALUE!.

```
=IF(FIND("Drummondville",B3)>0,"Drummondville",
IF(FIND("Saint-Germain-de-grantham",B3)>0,"Saint-Germain-de-grantham",
IF(FIND("Saint-cyrille-de-wendover",B3)>0,"Saint-cyrille-de-wendover","")))
```

[image: Excel snap]

Comment: Try: `=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH({"Drummondville","Saint-cyrille-de-wendover","Saint-Germain-de-grantham"},B2),{"Drummondville","Saint-cyrille-de-wendover","Saint-Germain-de-grantham"})`

Answer (score 3):

Try: You can either hard code the search words or create a reference range and name it as `Search_Word` and use with in a `LOOKUP()` Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2` --> Search Words hard-coded.

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,
SEARCH({"Drummondville","Saint-cyrille-de-wendover","Saint-Germain-de-grantham"},B2),
{"Drummondville","Saint-cyrille-de-wendover","Saint-Germain-de-grantham"})
```

---

• Formula used in cell `A11` --> When Search Key Words use from a define range

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(Search_Word,B11),Search_Word)
```

---

With `MS365` you could try using `FILTER()` `XMATCH()` & `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A11`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(B11," "),
FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,Search_Word))))
```

---

With One Single Array Formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A11`

```
=MAP(B11:B15,LAMBDA(m,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(m," "),
FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,Search_Word))))))
```

---